# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'HOME' in value "${HOME}"

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

While Running my Jhipster application with my prod profile, I am getting the above exception. I made my production application by using mvn -Pprod package. Whenever I try to run its jar file I get the above exception. I have posted the application.yml and application-prod.yml files below.

My application.yml is =>

```
# ===================================================================
# Spring Boot configuration.
#
# This configuration will be overridden by the Spring profile you use,
# for example application-dev.yml if you use the "dev" profile.
# More information on profiles: https://www.jhipster.tech/profiles/
# More information on configuration properties: https://www.jhipster.tech/common-application- 
properties/
# ===================================================================

# ===================================================================
# Standard Spring Boot properties.
# Full reference is available at:
# http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application- 
properties.html
# ===================================================================

---
# Conditionally disable springdoc on missing api-docs profile

logging:
  file:
    path: ${HOME}

spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: '!api-docs'
springdoc:
  api-docs:
    enabled: false
---
eureka:
  client:
    enabled: false
     healthcheck:
      enabled: true
    fetch-registry: true
    register-with-eureka: false
    instance-info-replication-interval-seconds: 10
    registry-fetch-interval-seconds: 10
  instance:
    appname: MyApp
    instanceId: MyApp:${spring.application.instance-id:${random.value}}
    lease-renewal-interval-in-seconds: 5
    lease-expiration-duration-in-seconds: 10
    status-page-url-path: ${management.endpoints.web.base-path}/info
    health-check-url-path: ${management.endpoints.web.base-path}/health
    metadata-map:
      zone: primary # This is needed for the load balancer
      profile: ${spring.profiles.active}
      version: #project.version#
      git-version: ${git.commit.id.describe:}
      git-commit: ${git.commit.id.abbrev:}
      git-branch: ${git.branch:}
      context-path: ${server.servlet.context-path:}
feign:
  circuitbreaker:
    enabled: true
  # client:
  #   config:
  #     default:
  #       connectTimeout: 5000
  #       readTimeout: 5000
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      base-path: /management
      exposure:
        include:
          [
            'configprops',
            'env',
            'health',
            'info',
            'jhimetrics',
            'jhiopenapigroups',
            'logfile',
            'loggers',
            'prometheus',
            'threaddump',
            'liquibase',
          ]
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: when_authorized
      roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN'
      probes:
        enabled: true
      group:
        liveness:
          include: livenessState
        readiness:
          include: readinessState,db
    jhimetrics:
      enabled: true
  info:
    git:
      mode: full
    env:
      enabled: true
  health:
    mail:
      enabled: false # When using the MailService, configure an SMTP server and set this to 
true
  metrics:
    export:
      # Prometheus is the default metrics backend
      prometheus:
        enabled: true
        step: 60
    enable:
      http: true
      jvm: true
      logback: true
      process: true
      system: true
    distribution:
      percentiles-histogram:
    all: true
  percentiles:
    all: 0, 0.5, 0.75, 0.95, 0.99, 1.0
tags:
  application: ${spring.application.name}
web:
  server:
    request:
      autotime:
        enabled: true

spring:
  application:
    name: MyApp
  profiles:
    # The commented value for `active` can be replaced with valid Spring profiles to load.

    # Otherwise, it will be filled in by maven when building the JAR file
    # Either way, it can be overridden by `--spring.profiles.active` value passed in the 
commandline or `-Dspring.profiles.active` set in `JAVA_OPTS`
    active: #spring.profiles.active#
    group:
      dev:
        - dev
        - api-docs
        # Uncomment to activate TLS for the dev profile
        #- tls
  jmx:
    enabled: false
  data:
    jpa:
      repositories:
        bootstrap-mode: deferred
  jpa:
    open-in-view: false
   properties:
      hibernate.jdbc.time_zone: UTC
      hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings: true
      hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit: true
      hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: false
      hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
      hibernate.generate_statistics: false
      # modify batch size as necessary
      hibernate.jdbc.batch_size: 25
      hibernate.order_inserts: true
      hibernate.order_updates: true
      hibernate.query.fail_on_pagination_over_collection_fetch: true
      hibernate.query.in_clause_parameter_padding: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
      naming:
        physical-strategy: 
org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy
        implicit-strategy: 
org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy
  messages:
    basename: i18n/messages
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
  mvc:
    pathmatch:
      matching-strategy: ant_path_matcher
  task:
    execution:
      thread-name-prefix: MyApp-task-
      pool:
       core-size: 2
        max-size: 50
        queue-capacity: 10000
    scheduling:
      thread-name-prefix: MyApp-scheduling-
      pool:
        size: 2
  thymeleaf:
    mode: HTML
  output:
    ansi:
      console-available: true

server:
  servlet:
    session:
      cookie:
        http-only: true

springdoc:
  show-actuator: true

# Properties to be exposed on the /info management endpoint
info:
  # Comma separated list of profiles that will trigger the ribbon to show
  display-ribbon-on-profiles: 'dev'

# ===================================================================
# JHipster specific properties
#
# Full reference is available at: https://www.jhipster.tech/common-application-properties/
# ===================================================================

jhipster:
  clientApp:
    name: 'MyApp'
    #By default CORS is disabled. Uncomment to enable.
  cors:
    allowed-origins: 'http://localhost:3000/,http://localhost:3001'
    allowed-methods: '*'
    allowed-headers: '*'
    exposed-headers: 'Authorization,Link,X-Total-Count,X-${jhipster.clientApp.name}- 
   alert,X-${jhipster.clientApp.name}-error,X-${jhipster.clientApp.name}-params'
       allow-credentials: true
        max-age: 1800
      mail:
        from: app@localhost
  api-docs:
    default-include-pattern: ${server.servlet.context-path:}/api/**
    management-include-pattern: ${server.servlet.context-path:}/management/**
    title: MyApp API
    description: MyApp API documentation
    version: 0.0.1
    terms-of-service-url:
    contact-name:
    contact-url:
    contact-email:
    license: unlicensed
    license-url:
#  security:
#    content-security-policy: "default-src 'self'; frame-src 'self' data:; script-src 'self' 
'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://storage.googleapis.com; style-src 'self' 
https://fonts.googleapis.com 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self' data:; font-src 'self' 
https://fonts.gstatic.com data:"
#security:
#    enabled: true # set to false to disable 'default' Spring Boot security

# ===================================================================
# Application specific properties
# Add your own application properties here, see the ApplicationProperties class
# to have type-safe configuration, like in the JHipsterProperties above
#
# More documentation is available at:
# https://www.jhipster.tech/common-application-properties/
# ===================================================================

# application:
```

My application-prod.yml is =>

```
# ===================================================================
# Spring Boot configuration for the "prod" profile.
#
# This configuration overrides the application.yml file.
#
# More information on profiles: https://www.jhipster.tech/profiles/
# More information on configuration properties: https://www.jhipster.tech/common-application-properties/
# ===================================================================

# ===================================================================
# Standard Spring Boot properties.
# Full reference is available at:
# http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application- 
properties.html
# ===================================================================
secret: random
logging:
  level:
    ROOT: INFO
    tech.jhipster: INFO
    org.hibernate.SQL: DEBUG
    com.suprb.myapp: INFO

eureka:
  instance:
    prefer-ip-address: true
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://admin:${jhipster.registry.password}@localhost:8761/eureka/

spring:
  devtools:
    restart:
      enabled: true
      additional-exclude: static/**
    livereload:
      enabled: false # we use Webpack dev server + BrowserSync for livereload
  jackson:
    serialization:
      indent-output: true
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://admin:${jhipster.registry.password}@localhost:8761/config

      # name of the config server's property source (file.yml) that we want to use
      name: MyApp
      profile: prod
      label: main # toggle to switch to a different version of the configuration as stored in git
      # it can be set to any label, branch or commit of the configuration source Git 
repository
  datasource:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    url: jdbc:mysql://11.100.152.145:3306/data?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false&tetimeCode= 
useLegacyDafalse&serverTimezone=GMT&connectionTimeZone=GMT&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
username: root
password: 
hikari:
  poolName: Hikari
  auto-commit: false
  data-source-properties:
    cachePrepStmts: true
    prepStmtCacheSize: 250
    prepStmtCacheSqlLimit: 2048
    useServerPrepStmts: true
  jpa:
  liquibase:
    # Remove 'faker' if you do not want the sample data to be loaded automatically
    contexts: dev, faker
  messages:
    cache-duration: PT1S # 1 second, see the ISO 8601 standard
  thymeleaf:
    cache: false
  sleuth:
    # https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/27844#issuescomment- 
   1002866885
# https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/issues/2094
async:
  enabled: false
enabled: false
sampler:
  probability: 1 # report 100% of traces
  zipkin: # Use the "zipkin" Maven profile to have the Spring Cloud Zipkin dependencies
    base-url: http://localhost:9411
    enabled: false
    locator:
      discovery:
        enabled: true

server:
  port: 8081

  # ===================================================================
  # JHipster specific properties
  #
  # Full reference is available at: https://www.jhipster.tech/common-application-properties/
  # ===================================================================

  #jhipster:
  #  registry:
  #    password: admin
  # CORS is disabled by default on microservices, as you should access them through a gateway.
  # If you want to enable it, please uncomment the configuration below.
  # cors:
  #   allowed-origins: "http://localhost:9000,https://localhost:9000"
  #   allowed-methods: "*"
  #   allowed-headers: "*"
  #   exposed-headers: "Authorization,Link,X-Total-Count"
  #   allow-credentials: true
  #   max-age: 1800
  #security:
  #  authentication:
  #    jwt:
  #      base-64secret: somerandomsecret
  #      token-validity-in-seconds: 86400
  #      token-validity-in-seconds-for-remember-me: 2592000

  logging:
    use-json-format: false # By default, logs are not in Json format
    logstash: # Forward logs to logstash over a socket, used by LoggingConfiguration
      enabled: false
      host: localhost
      port: 5000
      queue-size: 512
# ===================================================================
# Application specific properties
# Add your own application properties here, see the ApplicationProperties class
# to have type-safe configuration, like in the JHipsterProperties above
#
# More documentation is available at:
# https://www.jhipster.tech/common-application-properties/
# ===================================================================

# application:
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is happening because you didn’t export value for the env variable `$HOME`:

```
logging:
  file:
    path: ${HOME}
```

Either replace ${HOME} with value or export it in your terminal where you are running the application: `export HOME=path-here`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your prod file, the value $HOME is missing in your application-prod.yml. Remember you have it in one of your classes and it references your application-prod.yml. Immediately it cannot find it, and it becomes strange. Hence the error.

For Instance:

Let's say you have this

@Service

public class OrderServiceImpl implements OrderService {

@Value("${BASE_URL}")

private String baseURL;

}

In your application.properties file, you should have something like this:

BASE_URL=http://localhost:8080/

This class references directly from here.

In a case, we don't have the reference, then it throws:

"could not resolve the placeholder BASE_URL in @Value("${BASE_URL}")"